# Remove noise in video created by recordMyDesktop?

Tags: mp3, recordmydesktop, noise, audacity, avi

I need to record some activity on my desktop with voice , but recordMyDesktop really doesn't provide an acceptable record.
  Here are two solutions came into my mind ,

1. strip off the voice from that video , use audacity to remove
   noise , and put it back , but how ?
2. directly edit it , but what tool could do it ?

Thanks !

P.S: source file already encoded from .ogv to .avi with mencoder

Comment: Do you know the format of audio file and codec information? In any case it's probably transcoded from one format to MP3/MP2 (while you  converted from OGV to AVI) and you'll need to transcode once more if you want to filter noise, which will additionally degrade audio quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach is good one, you can add mp3 in KDENLIVE or Kino or may be several other video editor like pitivi. You can view the full list [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/top5-linux-video-editing-system-software/)

I hope you can find your solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=972485) also.

Some other helping sources:

1. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1692945
2. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/esmerge.1.html
3. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=899168